# RRDTool - Not a valid vname

Tags: bash, rrdtool

I am using **RRDTool** to manage and graph my Performance Data.
Currently, I am calling RRDTool from a *bash* script, but I get an Error, which I can not fix.
My Bash Script looks like this:

```
# Call RRDTool and save the output
output=$(rrdtool graph --width 4000 \
DEF:data=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/FM/win_tcpu.rrd:proc:AVERAGE \
VDEF:slope=data,LSLSLOPE \
PRINT:slope:'%lf')

echo "Output: " $output
```

I am trying to solve for *m* in *y = m*x + b* with this simple example.
My Performance Data looks something like this:

```
<NAGIOS>
<DATASOURCE>
  <TEMPLATE>nrpe_win_tcpu</TEMPLATE>
  <RRDFILE>/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/FM/win_tcpu.rrd</RRDFILE>
  <RRD_STORAGE_TYPE>SINGLE</RRD_STORAGE_TYPE>
  <RRD_HEARTBEAT>8460</RRD_HEARTBEAT>
  <IS_MULTI>0</IS_MULTI>
  <DS>1</DS>
  <NAME>proc</NAME>
  ...
</DATASOURCE>
...
```

As you can see the file name is correct and the DataSource Name is also correct.
My Problem is that the *DEF* does not seem to work. I get the following Error Message:

```
ERROR: Not a valid vname: data in line VDEF:slope=data,LSLSLOPE
```

When trying to access the data saved in Variable *data* like this, just to check if the problem is in my *VDEF* line:

```
LINE1:data#0000FF:"data" \
```

I get the following Error:

```
ERROR: parameter 'data' does not represent a number in line LINE1:data#0000FF:data
```

This clarifies that the problem is somewhere in the *DEF* line but I have no clue why this is happening.

Does anybody have an idea why I get these error messages and how to fix this problem?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was only a really dumb mistake I made.
I was calling:

```
rrdtool graph --width 4000 \
DEF:data=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/FM/win_tcpu.rrd:proc:AVERAGE \
VDEF:slope=data,LSLSLOPE \
...
```

Looking in the usage description of RRDTool graph again, showed me this:

```
rrdtool graph filename [-s|--start seconds] [-e|--end seconds] ...
```

I was simply **missing a filename**. When calling it like mentioned above RRDTool interpreted my *DEF* line as a filename. This would cause an error when writing the result to this file, but RRDTool exits with an error on the VDEF line, since *data* was never defined.

Thanks for all the comments. I just wanted to clarify some things I tested:
 - The variable Name *data* does not cause any problems
 - It is totally working to have a DS with name *1* and you could also access it in a CDEF and so on

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a line of a `VDEF` - it's a value, and is only valid with an aggregation function.

From: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph_rpn.en.html LSLSLOPE is valid.

You should be able to graph `data` though, e.g.

```
LINE1:data#00CC00:data
```

That you can't - and get 'does not represent a number' makes me wonder what's in you data source. I would suggest you have a look at `xport` to dump the RRD and see what's in there.

You might well be not getting enough input data to build a CDP within your RRD, and so they're all `UNKNOWN` or `NaN`.

(Invalid VNAME does make me wonder though - have you tried changing it to something other than `data`  - which seems like it could be a reserved word.)

Comment: I tried to do a line of my _DEF_, just to test if my _VDEF_ is working and my _DEF_ is the problem.

Comment: On that point then - do you definitely have an AVERAGE RRA in your data source?

Comment: I tried doing it with xport, but there seems to be no DS named 'proc' in my RRD. I called xport with:
`rrdtool xport DEF:data=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/FM/win_tcpu.rrd:proc:AVERAGE`
Knowing this I dumped my RRD to XML. The Name of the Datasource seems to be **1**.
Exporting with DS Name 1 throws this:
ERROR: no XPORT found, nothing to do
Also my dump is showing me that there is data saved in this RRD.

Comment: Looking at my Dump I have a DataSource with name **1** in my RRD and it also contains the AVERAGE. Changing the DS Name to 1 in my DEF does not  solve the problem.

Comment: You don't say which version of rrdtool you're using, which may help.
It seems that your DEF line is incorrect, and so the 'data' series is not being defined, but the RRDTool parser is not giving an error message for this but isinstead continuing and giving you the error about the VDEF.  The fix is to correct your DEF of course, but if you are using a recent RRDTool versoin, it might help to report the bug to Tobi so that the error message can be fixed to be more helpful.

Comment: Note that it is not legal to have a DS name consisting only of numbers (although it allows you to create it, you cannot reference it in a DEF or CDEF).  You will need to rename your DS to somthing else.

Comment: I am using **RRDTool 1.4.8**. I renamed the DS into _proc_. rrdtool dump and rrdtool fetch show me there is a Variable with name _proc_ and there ist data without _NaN_, but I get the same error message again. Also I renamed my _DEF_ Variable name from _data_ into _myvar_ to check if this causes a problem.